# Orthogonal matrix multiplication written as outer product of columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I see the following formula in the textbook:

$UU^T = \sum_{i=1}^n u_iu_i^T = I$, where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix

I'm trying to prove the first equality in the formula. I know it can be proved by tediously writing out every element of $UU^T$, but I think there should be a more elegant proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly elegant...

$U U^T x = U \sum_k  ( u_k^T x ) e_k = \sum_k  ( u_k^T x ) U e_k  = \sum_k  ( u_k^T x ) u_k =  \sum_k  u_k ( u_k^T x ) = \sum_k  u_k u_k^T x $.

Hence $U U^T = \sum_k  u_k u_k^T $.

Comment: Can you show me how to cancel out the $x$ from both sides?

Comment: If $Ax = Bx$ for all $x$ then, by definition, you have $A=B$.

Comment: But $x$ is inside the summation on the right hand side?

Comment: Use the distributive property! $\sum_k u_k u_k^T x = \sum_k ( u_k u_k^T ) x =(\sum_k u_k u_k^T )x $.

Comment: Ahh somehow I didn't realize every $u_ku_k^T$ is a matrix. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One easy method is with block matrices.  In particular, if the $u_i$ are column-vectors, we have
$$
UU^T = 
\pmatrix{u_1 & \cdots & u_n}
\pmatrix{u_1^T \\ \vdots \\u_n^T } = 
\sum_{i=1}^n u_iu_i^T
$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for a simple explanation!